# Two doubts about proof of Doob's Martingale Inequalities Theorem on Jacod-Protter

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, inequality, proof-explanation, martingales

I quote **Jacod-Protter**.

> **Theorem** Let $M=(M_n)_{n\geq0}$ be a martingale and define $M_n^*=\sup_{j\leq n}|M_j|$. Let $1 < p < \infty$. There exists a constant $c$ depending only on $p$ such that 
>   \begin{equation}
> \mathbb{E}\{(M_n^*)^p\} \leq c\mathbb{E}\{|M_n|^p\}
> \end{equation}

The proof of the above theorem ends in the following manner:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\{(M_n^*)^p\}\leq\int_0^{\infty}p2p\lambda^{p-2}\mathbb{E}\{|M_n|\mathbb{1}_{\{|M_n|>\frac{\lambda}{2}\}}\}d\lambda = \mathbb{E}\{\int_0^{2|M_n|}2p\lambda^{p-2}d\lambda|M_n|\}=\frac{2^{p}p}{p-1}\mathbb{E}\{|M_n|^{p}\}
\end{equation}

At this point, the theorem is considered as proven and it is stated that

> *we showed in the proof of above theorem that the constant $c\leq \frac{2^p p}{p-1}$. With more work one can show that $c^{\frac{1}{p}}=\frac{p}{p-1}$*

As to the last line above, I would have two doubts and, as a consequence, two observations:

**FIRST**:

Considering the way in which the theorem is stated, I think it would be correct to state that *the constant $c\geq\frac{2^p p}{p-1}$* (that is, $c$ is **at least** equal to $\frac{2^p p}{p-1}$ for the above theorem inequality to hold true) and **NOT** *the constant $c\leq\frac{2^p p}{p-1}$* (that is, $c$ is **at most** equal to $\frac{2^p p}{p-1}$ for the above theorem inequality to hold true)

**SECOND**:

I would say that $c^{\frac{1}{p}}=\frac{2(p)^{\frac{1}{p}}}{{(p-1)}^{\frac{1}{p}}}=2(\frac{p}{p-1})^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and **NOT** that $c^{\frac{1}{p}}=\frac{p}{p-1}$

*Are my observations correct?*

Comment: Why is this algebra-precalculus?

Comment: I guess because of symbolic manipulation in my second observation, when I raise r.h.s and l.h.s to $\frac{1}{p}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first doubt :

> *we showed in the proof of above theorem that the constant $c\leq \frac{2^p p}{p-1}$.*

I think that the meaning of this sentence is basically as follows :

"(We want to find $c$ such that $\mathbb{E}\{(M_n^*)^p\} \leq c\mathbb{E}\{|M_n|^p\}$.) We showed in the proof of above theorem that **such $c$ can be found at least in** $c\leq \frac{2^p p}{p-1}$."

You are correctly claiming that $\mathbb{E}\{(M_n^*)^p\} \leq c\mathbb{E}\{|M_n|^p\}$ holds for every $c$ satisfying $c\color{red}{\ge} \frac{2^p p}{p-1}$, but I don't think that this is what the sentence is trying to say.

---

For the second doubt :

> *With more work one can show that $c^{\frac{1}{p}}=\frac{p}{p-1}$*

I think that the meaning of this sentence is basically as follows :

"There is **another way** to show that $\mathbb{E}\{(M_n^*)^p\} \leq (\frac{p}{p-1})^{p}\mathbb{E}\{|M_n|^p\}$ holds (where $(\frac{p}{p-1})^{p}$ is smaller than $\frac{2^pp}{p-1}$)."

I don't think that the sentence means that $c^{\frac 1p}=\frac{p}{p-1}$ follows from $c=\frac{2^pp}{p-1}$.

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot for your answer.
Secondly, as to my second doubt I got your point, the explanation is clear.
On the other hand, as to the first one, what do you mean with "**such c can be found at least in $c\leq\frac{2^pp}{p-1}$**"? There is something I cannot get.
@mathlove

Comment: @user600927 : OK. Let me explain the part. Let $C$ be the **least possible** $c$ such that the inequality holds. Since we already know that the inequality holds for $c=\frac{2^pp}{p-1}$, we can say that $C\le\frac{2^pp}{p-1}$. I hope this could help.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, it's kinda of stating that..$c$ is a good candidate for the **least possibile** constant $C$ so as for the inequality to hold true, but there could be some other constant lower than $c$ granting the validity of the inequality.
However (sorry if I keep on asking, it's just to have a clear comprehension), I cannot convince myself how the statement $C<c=\frac{2^pp}{p-1}$ can be compatible with the statement $c\geq\frac{2^pp}{p-1}$. How can I be sure about the fact that inequality holds true also for some $C<c$? @mathlove

Comment: @user600927: Let me explain that in another way :) (Using $C$ was not a good explanation, sorry) Let $c(max)$ be such that if $c\ge c(max)$, then the inequality holds, but if $c\lt c(max)$, then the inequality does not holds. We already know that $c(max)\le \frac{2^pp}{p-1}$, right? The inequality $c\le \frac{2^pp}{p-1}$ in the sentence should mean that $c(max)\le \frac{2^pp}{p-1}$ which means that we can at least say that $\frac{2^pp}{p-1}$ is an upper bound for $c(max)$. Does this explanation help?

Comment: Yeah, now I got it. Thank you a lot for your patience and all your help :D @mathlove

Comment: "There is another way to show..." I second that. It is in fact shown in many textbooks, e.g. our book with Yuliya Mishura (Theorem 5.12).

Comment: I cannot find such a Theorem 5.12 in Yuliya Mishura. Is the reference correct? @zhoraster

Comment: Which is the exact title of the book? @zhoraster

Comment: @user600927 Theory and Statistical Applications of Stochastic Processes

Comment: Thank you very much @zhoraster